# Cover a polygon with least amount of parallelograms

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, polygons

I am solving the task that is as follows:

**Input:** a polygon. Can be any kind of polygon without self intersections. Can be a non-convex and with holes inside.

**Goal:** to cover it with 2 (at least) or more parallelograms that together are equal to or contain the whole polygon. The following criteria should be met:

- There is no point of the polygon that lies beyond parallelograms.
- The number of the parallelograms should be the least possible. I.e. we want to find largest parallelograms that cover the polygon.
- These parallelograms must not intersect within the polygon.

**Question:** Is this task solved and if it is solved - how? I am looking for a direction where to start with and what related algorithms/theory to learn.

Comment: Cross-posted on three sites - not good...

Comment: @HEKTO The audience differ between sites, doesn't it?

Comment: Rules are rules... Please read about cross-posting on SE

Comment: @HEKTO no arguing, I'm sorry. Will not do that again.